# Dune Film Deleted Ending Scene

Tags: dune, deleted-scenes, dune-1984

In the 1984 David Lynch film adaption of Dune, I remember seeing a video clip of Reverend Mother Gaius Helen Mohiam saying to Paul, "You cannot loose these people upon the universe!" She said this at the end of the movie when Paul and the Fremen had captured the Emperor and his court. This is straight out of the novel and foretells Paul's imminent jihad, setting up the rest of the sequels.

Anybody remember seeing this clip of the movie and if so where I can I find it? I would love to see this again.

Comment: There is a fan edit on YouTube that lasts about 3+hours includes lots of deleted scenes, drowning sandworms and the Jamis fight etc. I'll try and find link.

Answer (score 3):

I think I saw the scene you are referring to in what's called the "Third Stage Edition" of the movie. The [IMDBs alternate versions list](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087182/alternateversions) states:

> A third version of "Dune", seen on KTVU in San Francisco in 1992, is
>   the only one that edits together footage from both the theatrical and
>   TV versions, putting back the violent scenes (such as the "heart
>   sucking sequence") and theatrical versions of some scenes (such as
>   Paul and Jessica running from a thumper).